# I am getting this error while opening library Rserve

Tags: r, rserve

I am first downloading Rserve from nearest mirror and then loading the library which is giving me this error

```
 > install.packages("Rserve")
    Installing package into ‘C:/Users/abc/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
    (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
    --- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
    trying URL 'http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/Rserve_1.7-3.zip'
    Content type 'application/zip' length 632080 bytes (617 KB)
    downloaded 617 KB

    package ‘Rserve’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

    The downloaded binary packages are in
            C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmGy9pG\downloaded_packages
    > Rserve()
    Error in Rserve() : could not find function "Rserve"
```

Comment: You need to import the package first before calling the `Rserve` function: `library(Rserve); Rserve()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing a `R` package is different than attaching the package to your computer's memory. As an an analogy, think about installing a software program (from, say, a CD). After installing the program onto your computer, you need to open it up in order to use it.

The way to attach a `R` package to your computer's memory is: `library(package name)`, where "package name" is replaced by whichever package(s) you want to load. For example, you would put `library(Rserve)` somewhere in the beginning of your script.